# Counting Multiple Values from Dependent Table Relationship

Tags: sql, group-by, psql

I'm working on a problem where I'm calculating the number of instances that occur in a dependent table that meet a few different criteria. An example for working through this problem is below:

```
Owners Table:
 - owner_id
 - owner_name


Pets Table:
 - pet_id
 - owner_id
 - category
```

I'm interested in locating information on the number of pets of a certain category belong to a user. For example, if I was curious as to the number of mammals that a particular user had, I could perform the following query:

```
SELECT
   owners.*,
   mammals.mammal_count
FROM
   owners
JOIN (
   SELECT
      owner_id,
      COUNT(*) as mammal_count
   FROM
      pets
   WHERE
      category = 'mammal'
   GROUP BY
      owner_id
   ) mammals on mammals.owner_id = owners.id
```

Which would return the number of mammals that belong to each user. What I'm interested in is creating another query that allows me to know how many times another criteria appears, for example, 'birds'. I know that I can't inner join the records, because an owner may or may not have one of the categories and if they don't they'll be excluded from the result. That being said, I've tried a variety of outer joins, none of which seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation

```
select 
    o.owner_id,
    o.owner_name,
    sum(case when p.category = 'mammal' then 1 else 0 end) mammal_count,
    sum(case when p.category = 'birds' then 1 else 0 end) bird_count
from 
    owners o
    inner join pets p on p.owner_id = o.id
group by o.owner_id, o.owner_name
```

Answer (score -1):

This should also work:

```
select 
    o.owner_id
    ,o.owner_name
    ,p.category
    ,[Count of Pets] = count(pet_id)

from owners o
left join pets p on p.owner_id = o.id

group by 
    o.owner_id
    ,o.owner_name
    ,p.category
```